# Are the FIPS 186-5 and ANSI X9.142-2020 definitions of ECDSA consistent?

Tags: elliptic-curves, dsa

[FIPS 186-4](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/fips/186/4/final) *Digital Signature Standard* defers to ANSI X9.62-2005 for the specification of ECDSA, with additional requirements set out in Chapter 6 and Appendix D. However, X9.62-2005 has since been withdrawn and replaced by [ANSI X9.142-2020](https://x9.org/asc-x9-issues-new-standard-for-public-key-cryptography-ecdsa/). The [FIPS 186-5 draft](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/fips/186/5/draft) noted the withdrawal of X9.62-2005 and that X9.142 was under development (Appendix E, p. 78), and instead gives its own specification of ECDSA in Chapter 6 (with recommended curve parameters moved to [SP 800-186](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-186/draft)).

I haven't scaled the ANSI paywall to read X9.142-2020 but the freely-available preview ([PDF](https://webstore.ansi.org/preview-pages/ASCX9/preview_ANSI+X9.142-2020.pdf), p. xv) notes a number of technical changes from X9.62-2005:

- New examples of elliptic curve domain parameters and signatures.
- Provision for new hash functions.
- New recommendations and requirements for elliptic curve domain parameters.
- New specifications for assurance of domain parameter validity, assurance of public key validity, and assurance of private key possession.
- New random number generation method.
- New syntax.

It also notes that FIPS 186-4 "contains much in common with both this Standard and the previous ANSI X9.62-2005 version, particularly in regard to elliptic curve domain parameters and the elliptic curve digital signature algorithm", but is silent on FIPS 186-5.

My question is, how consistent are the FIPS 186-5 and X9.142-2020 specifications of ECDSA? Specifically, in a contractual or regulatory setting where detailed conformance matters (and pretending FIPS 186-5 has been approved as-is), is it true given an appropriate choice of parameters that:

1. Conformance with the FIPS 186-5 specification of ECDSA implies conformance with X9.142-2020?
2. Conformance with X9.142-2020 implies conformance with the FIPS 186-5 specification?

Or are the two specifications inconsistent no matter what parameters are chosen, meaning implementations need to choose between them?

Answer (score 1):

Many FIPS standards are modified versions of standards used in broader communities, from my experience, conformance with the FIPS 186-5 specification of ECDSA implies conformance with X9.142-2020, and not backwards.

Comment: It would be useful to add an example of FIPS 186-5 requirement not in X9.142-2020